# How to run this javascript offline?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to have offline the functionality of this javascript: [jspretty](http://prettydiff.com/lib/jspretty.js). I know that I can get the same online, but I want it offline.

How can I run the js above?

Comment: save the code in the [link](http://prettydiff.com/lib/jspretty.js) to a js file and refer to that local js file

Comment: you can execute a .js file in your browser locally, so as @Slayermoah mentioned, save the code into a .js file, and load it in your browser with the url `file://path/to/the/file.js`. That said, unless there is a driver function, it won't do anything, so executing a javascript library isn't really helpful. you would have to create a stub/driver javascript that links to and calls functions within the library.

Comment: @FrankThomas Not sure if `file://` would work when referencing js files. I would put the code on a local web server and use a url to access the local js like: `<script src="http://localhost/jspretty.js".` or access it using a relative path like: `<script src="../jspretty.js">` or `<script src="../somefolder/jspretty.js">`

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the code in the [link](http://prettydiff.com/lib/jspretty.js) to a file with a `js` extension. Example: `jspretty.js`
2. Place the `.js` file in a folder on the local computer that is accessible over a local web server. i.e. usually in a folder like: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\`, `c:\apache\htdocs\`, `c:\xampp\htdocs\`, `c:\wamp\www\`, `/var/www/` etc. (These are only examples of some default web server paths and is ok for development environments IMO. But not recommended for production environments)
3. Refer to that local `.js` file on a web page using absolute or relative paths.

Example:

```
<script src="http://localhost/folder/jspretty.js">
```

or

```
<script src="jspretty.js">
```

or

```
<script src="/folder/jspretty.js">
```

or

```
<script src="../jspretty.js">
```

or

```
<script src="../folder/jspretty.js">
```

For details on relative and absolute paths see:

1. [Difference between Relative path and absolute path in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306512)
2. [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079)
3. [Paths and URLs; relative and absolute](http://jeffreybarke.net/2013/06/paths-and-urls-relative-and-absolute/)